# Is there an rss parser that works with rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3

Are there any rss parsing solutions that work with the latest rails 3 beta?

Answer (score 1):

Check out feedzirra. The fork out here: http://github.com/colinsurprenant/feedzirra has support for rails 3 beta though i have not tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

All RSS parser don't depend of Rails 3. So it's works.